# git merge replaces one branch without actually merging them

Tags: git, git-merge

I am trying to merge `branch-to-safely-merge-pav-origin` with `pj-master`

[image]

the directory structure of the branch `pj-master`:

[image]

the directory structure of the branch `branch-to-safely-merge-pav-origin`:

[image]

After the merge the content of the `pj-master` is being replaced (not merged) by the contents of the `branch-to-safely-merge-pav-origin`. No attempt to merge, no conflicts (andfor sure  there are conflicts). Any clues?

Comment: *How* did you merge? Through a pull request? Locally then pushed? CLI or GUI? Give us details :-)

Comment: maybe the commit '--empty but related' or 'dummy commit' removes historical directory. as base of your pj-master is quite old (2 commits) the merge will embed this commit and remove them. If your pj-master includes conflicts you should maybe try to configure your merge strategy to reveal conflicts instead of silently resolve with one branch

Comment: @RomainValeri it is local. Tried GUI and command line

Comment: @boly38  to be honest I am not very good in git :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the files were present in `pj-master~` and they were deleted in one of the revisions that takes you to `branch-to-safely-merge-pav-origin`. So.... the trick is to understand what was at the last revision present on both branches (`pj-master~`). Looking at the tips of the 2 branches is just not enough.